# How to get a single row value of dataframe reading from parquet files in a Dask?

Tags: python, dask

Problem: The DASK dataframe

```
loc[concrete_row, concrete_column]
```

return  pandas data frame with multiple rows, each with the same index:

```
0                   [1,2,3]
0                   [1,2]
0                   [3]
```

instead of one row value.

```
0                   [1,2,3]
```

I am reading many parquet files:

```
dd.read_parquet(dataset_dir+'/train/date*/*.parquet')
```

Each row in parquet file has a array!!!

- It seems that when calling concrete row the dask dataframe return all partitions values with this row index of each partition.
- When read from parquet files all divisions is none
- I try to set_index and set divisions but its become too slow

I need to call map function for each row and get iterable values of this concrete row.
How to i resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to call map function for each row and get iterable values of this concrete row.

It sounds like you want the map or apply methods.

```
def func(row):
    return ...

result = df.apply(func)
```

In general parallel computing tools like Dask are poorly suited to get data one row at a time.  Instead it's common to apply a function across all of your rows in parallel.

Comment: MY question is: "how to get single row value..." , not how to call the map func. When i call map i get the multiple rows with same index.  It seems the problem is in DataFrame index (seems in need the unique index for every row), and another problem that after reading files, DASK NOT automatically set Divisions, and DataFrame divisions is None.